# javascript and silverlight obfuscation!

Tags: javascript, security, silverlight-4.0, obfuscation

i am having few issues with obfuscation for last few days .

firstly i would like to obfuscate my javascript code such that variables and function names get obfuscated .any free or cheap recommended software.

secondly , for my silverlight app i would like following

1. i would like my library project (silverlight library) to get obfuscated .  because if i dont , things get very clear and easy to decompile.if i obfuscate public members , the resultant xap is not runnable ( tested using both .net reactor and crypto obfuscator)
2. on my wcf service end, for datacontracts(table name and column name) and service operations i would like their names to get obfuscated . and if i dont , the whole datamodel gets revealed.i am using linqtosql on the service and by setting the serialisation mode to unidirectional , datamember attributes are automatically annotation .

please suggest optimal solutions.

Answer (score 3):

What you are hoping to do is inherently impossible. You will not achieve any kind of security that way. Whatever you do anyone with some free time and a little help from the [JavaScript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) will be able to understand what your script is doing. Search Stack Overflow for [javascript obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+obfuscation) to read more about it.

Comment: About this matter, I would recommend a search for [security through obscurity](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=security+through+obscurity), starting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: Having some experience cracking these "obscured" js files myself. I can say that obscuring only entices more because of the challenge.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT SILVERILIGHT APPLICATION OBFUSCATION QUESTION POSTED ?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript obfuscation (as a side effect of optimization): [Google's Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)

Answer (score 0):

The Dojo Toolkit is compatible (after some modifications) with the Closure Compiler's Advanced mode.

After advanced mode compilation, your JavaScript code is essentially non-comprehensible.

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

- Stephen